# Viewpager with fragments And Another Fragmnet replace

Tags: android, android-fragments

viewpager with multiple fragment in activity,but i hope switch another simple fragment replace this viewpager, how do I replace it, I usually switch fragments, I don't known how to switch a fragment and a viewpager with fragments. if someone have solve method , please tell me or give me some hint ,thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the latest support library v4 (maybe you need to update it) you can nest fragment inside fragment, which means that you can put your ViewPager inside Fragment (call getChildFragmentManager() instead of getSupportFragmentManager() )

Then you can switch between fragment containing ViewPager and the other fragment you want to display.

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {
private ViewPager pager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    return v;
}

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            // inside fragment use getChildFragmentManager()
            // to pass to your adapter
mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());

            pager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }
}
```